# android studio. build,gradle - Could not find property, after importing project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting the following error after importing some project.
the project was originally taken from GitHub.

it happens after upgrading to gradle 2.10

```
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView
```

this is the error I am getting.

```
Error:(3, 0) Could not find property 'GROUP' on project ':library'.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Edi\Google Drive\Android\AndroidStudio_Projects\HorizontalListView\library\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

this is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

group GROUP
version VERSION_NAME

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'

}


apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sephiroth74/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: why have you added `GROUP` in gradle. In library's page it is nowhere written that it is required

Answer (score 1):

```
    in the settings.gradle their is
 include ':app', ':library'

    he is not able to find that library edit it and write
    include ':app'
```

Comment: my settings.gradle looks like this.
include ':app', ':library', ':demo'   .  what sould I change in this code

Comment: change  include ':app', ':library', ':demo' to include ':app'

Comment: my settings.gradle looks like this
include ':app', ':library', ':demo'
what should i change ?

Comment: change to include ':app'